# Agrupadores de Interseção e Subtração

Tags: java, regex

Tenho uma dúvida referente a expressões regulares. Não entendo como funcionam a intersecção e a subtração em expressões regulares. Alguém poderia me esclarecer?

```
[a-z&&[aeiou]]  Interseção
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   Subtração
```

```java
System.out.println("O QUE PODE FICAR AQUI PARA SER VERDADEIRO?".matches("[a-z&&[aeiou]]"));
System.out.println("O QUE PODE FICAR AQUI PARA SER VERDADEIRO?".matches("[a-z&&[^m-p]]"));
```

Comment: O que você quer fazer?

Comment: Só estou querendo entender esses dois tipos.

Comment: Você quer saber se uma *regex* captura algo? se possível explique melhor o que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o nome já diz, a intersecção fará a intersecção de duas expressões regulares. Ou seja, a intersecção de *n* expressões regulares é uma expressão regular que vai dar *match* se todas as *n* subexpressões também derem *match*.

Já a subtração de uma expressão regular *a* por uma expressão *b* vai dar *match* apenas se a expressão *a* der *match* e a expressão regular *b* não der.

No caso da expressão `[a-z&&[aeiou]]`, a `String` `a` dá *match* na subexpressão `a-z` e também dá *match* na subexpressão `[aeiou]`. Logo ele dá *match* na expressão `[a-z&&[aeiou]]`. Por outro lado, a `String` `b` só dá *match* na primeira subexpressão, e portanto ele não dá *match* na expressão completa.

No caso da expressão `[a-z&&[^m-p]]`, a `String` `a` dá *match* na subexpressão `a-z` e também dá *match* na subexpressão `[^m-p]` (porque `a` não está entre `m` e `p`). Logo ele dá *match* na expressão `[a-z&&[^m-p]]`. Por outro lado, a `String` `m` dá *match* na primeira subexpressão, mas não dá *match* na segunda porque `m` está entre `m` e `p`, e portanto ele não dá *match* na expressão completa.